# What are the differences between a thin client, light client, and validator?

Tags: validator

based on the [terminology page](https://docs.solana.com/terminology), a thin client does no verification and must trust an upstream validator, and a validator obviously is a full validating node with all that entails. a light client, according to the same page, "can verify it's pointing to a valid cluster" and "performs more ledger verification than a thin client and less than a validator"

what exactly does a light client do (and not do) that differs from a thin client and a validator? does the reduced verification compared to a true validator make its data less trustworthy to its operator?

Comment: please try to reduce the scope here to a single question. more posts is fine!